# Google Sheets Formula: Map String Value in Dropdown to Number for use in Formula?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, vlookup

Let's say I have a cell A1 with possible dropdown values {Apple,Banana,Cherry}. The chosen string determines which constant to use in the formula for B1. What is the best way to do this in Google Sheets?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

if `{Apple,Banana,Cherry}` = `{1,2,3}` then try:

```
=MATCH(A1, {"Apple"; "Banana"; "Cherry"}, 0)
```

or:

```
=VLOOKUP(A1, {"Apple", 1; "Banana", 2; "Cherry", 3}, 2, 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a lot of dropdown options, a lookup table is the best way to approach this. Otherwise SWITCH() > IFS() > IF().

If you are having trouble implement this please share a dummy sheet.